# Function can't see change in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-scope, mean

I got this two functions

Function 1

```
    $scope.selected = [];
    $scope.selected.project = ['name:test, id:1'];
    $scope.selectedFs = function($item, $model) {
            $scope.selected.project = [$model];
        console.log($scope.selected.project[0]);
       }
    };
```

Function 2

```
$scope.create = function() {
        var sign = new Sign ({
            sig: document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL(),
            projectId:  $scope.proid,
            project: $scope.selected.project[0],
            timesheetId:  $scope.timesheetsId
        });
        console.log($scope.selected.project[0]);

        sign.$save(function(response) {

         }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };
}
]);
```

When i call function 1, i can see that selected.project change in console, but when i use function 2 after, it just uses ['name:test, id:1']

TEST

```
selectedFs('1','1') ->
CONSOLE = [1] ->
create() ->
CONSOLE = ['name:test, id:1']
```

Why dosen't function 2 have the new value ?

Comment: Your $scope.selected.project is undefined. Where do you set it?

Comment: @Tom  console.log($scope.selected.project) gives undefind and  console.log($scope.selected.project) gives same typeError

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my comment! See above.

Comment: @Tom http://pastebin.com/ME4dBTqx

Comment: @Tom just edited my question

Comment: I'm confused; now $scope.selected.project isn't undefined? What did you change?

Comment: @Tom  $scope.selected.project = ['name:test, id:1'];   but create() doesn't read what selectedFs() assigns selected.project, it reads  ['name:test, id:1'] instead :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first function contains this line:

```
$scope.selected.project = [$model];
```

So, if you set $model to 1 (which you do in the line above), it will, of course, return [1].

In your second function, I can't see $scope.selected.project on the left-hand side of any assignment, so it simply isn't assigned the value of `[1]`.

Comment: So how do i assign the value, to selected.project in selectedFs() properly

Comment: `$scope.select.project = [1]`? I don't really have enough information to know where you want to get its value from - is this function taken from a controller with some more information in it?

Comment: its an controller, and in my view i first run the function selectFs with a input + button() and then after i run create () also with a button
So shouldn't create get the value of the input, after i called that function first.

Comment: If you're still stuck with this, it would probably be easier to show me some code. Otherwise, I hope you've got this sorted :)